# MongoDB : How to separate the log file by date?

Tags: mongodb, file, date, logging

I'd like to separate the log files by date.
For instance,

```
MongoDB2015-08-23.log
MongoDB2015-08-24.log
MongoDB2015-08-25.log
```

I cannot find the way to do this.
Did I miss some options in the config file?

My mongodb config file is below.

```
systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: C:/MongoDB/MongoDB.log
 logAppend: true
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a cron job (scheduled task) that will rename

`MongoDB.log` to `MongoDB2015-08-23.log`in the last seconds (if possible) right before the date will change to `2015-08-24`, for example.

Here I brought up a specific date, but you will need to make it generic.